# Custom LoginPath no effect in ASP.NET MVC with Auth0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, auth0

In my ASP.NET MVC project, the default login path is `/Account/Login`. I want to configure It to be `/User/Login` when `[Authorize]` tag is used on the controller.

The following is the relevant code in Program.cs, it seems the setting in `ConfigureApplicationCookie` has no effect. It still redirects to `/Account/Login`.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
using Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(devConnString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/User/Login");
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/User/Logout");
});

builder.Services.AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Domain = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseResponseCaching();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication` will configure a cookie using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` which has a value of `"Cookies"`.

`ConfigureApplicationCookie` will configure a cookie using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` which has a value of `"Identity.Application"`.

Remove the `ConfigureApplicationCookie` invocation, and replace it with your own CookieAuthenticationOptions configuration using the same scheme as the Auth0 library.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

//...

builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
});
```

Or you can continue to use `ConfigureApplicationCookie`, but you'll need to tell Auth0 to use it as its cookie authentication scheme.

```
builder.Services.AddAuth0WebAppAuthentications(options => {
    options.CookieAuthenticationScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    //...
});
```

If you choose this option, be sure to update your sign out logic with the cookie scheme your using.

```
//...
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, logoutProps);
//await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
```

Answer (score -1):

add the UseAuthentication middleware to the request pipeline as follows:

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production
    // scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

// Add the UseAuthentication middleware
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```