Authentication/Authorization in Blazor with Some Unsecured Pages
I am struggling to get Authentication/Authorization working in Blazor in combination with having some public pages (like login, privacy policy, error pages, etc.).  After much tinkering it seems to be working, but I can't imagine the way I've done it is the recommended way.  I am using Auth0 for authentication--I'm not sure that matters (probably not).
I'm using a Blazor server Web App with .Net 8, which was converted from a .Net 7 Blazor Server app.
I won't post the whole Routes.razor, but it references MainLayout (as I think is standard):
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">

MainLayout.razor then has an AuthorizedView with a few layers of Authentication.  The @Body is nested in an ErrorBoundary inside the Authorized section, with a second @Body tag in the NotAuthorized section (only a partial snippet below):
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
       [...]
            <ErrorBoundary @ref="_errorBoundary">
                <ChildContent>
                    @Body
                </ChildContent>
                <ErrorContent Context="ex">
                    @{
                        OnError(ex);
                    }
                    <p>Something has gone wrong. The error has been logged.</p>
                </ErrorContent>
            </ErrorBoundary>
       [...]
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
       @Body
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

The code behind (MainLayout.razor.cs) does the following on Init:
private static readonly List<string> PublicUris = new() { "/privacy", "/login", "/error" };

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authenticationStateAsync = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    User = authenticationStateAsync.User;

    var baseUri = NavigationManager.BaseUri.TrimEnd('/');

    //TODO: is this how it needs to work?
    //Note: all public pages would have to be added to this page?
    var publicPage = PublicUris.Select(p => baseUri + p).Contains(NavigationManager.Uri);
    
    if (User.Identity is not { IsAuthenticated: true } && !publicPage)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/{UnauthorizedRedirectUrl}");
    }

    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

It's a little clunky, but the gist is that if the current page is not a public page and the user in not logged in, redirect to the login page.
Some of Program.cs.  Not sure how much is relevant:
builder.Services
    .AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication(options => {[...]

//added based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74555220/custom-loginpath-no-effect-in-asp-net-mvc-with-auth0
builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Logout";
});
[...]
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{[policies that I don't think are relevant]...
[...]
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

Again, this appears to work, and public pages can be seen whether logged in or not and don't require an AllowAnonymous attribute in order to be seen.
That said, I haven't found an article anywhere recommending doing it this way, or saying anything about examining the current Uri in the code behind of the main layout page and redirecting.
How can I support both secure and public pages in a Blazor app without having to engineer something like the above?

You could add @attribute [Authorize] to _Imports.razor to make the authorize global. Then add @attribute [AllowAnonymous] to the public pages.
If you want using a list of public page Uris, you could keep the @attribute [Authorize],then add a custom authorization handler to determine the auth result based on request Uri.
MyAuthHandler.cs
    public class MyAuthHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

        private static readonly List<string> PublicUris = new() { "/counter", "/login", "/error" };
        public MyAuthHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            this.accessor = accessor;
        }

        public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
        {

            var currentUri = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Path;

            var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();

            foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
            {
                if (PublicUris.Contains(currentUri))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

Then in the program.cs
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(...);

Just note that all registered "IAuthorizationHandler" will be foreached by defualt authorization service.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-8.0#iauthorizationservice
